# How to use a date in a logical condition in Dialogflow CX

Tags: date, conditional-statements, dialogflow-cx

I am brand new to Dialogflow CX and am having trouble figuring out how to use a date in a condition. I want to require that a birthdate be entered and be greater than 2000-01-01. I have tried

```
$intent.params.dob.resolved > 2005-01-01
```

with and without quotes, but it does not work (always false). I discovered that `$intent.params.dob.original > "1/1/01"` is resolved as True for all dates, so that is of no help.

Is there a way that works?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your described use case, you can utilize the [condition route](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route) or [conditional response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#cond) to return a response according to the condition. Here is a condition you may use:

```
$intent.params.birthdate.resolved.year > 2000 OR 
($intent.params.birthdate.resolved.year = 2000 AND 
$intent.params.birthdate.resolved.month > 1) OR 
($intent.params.birthdate.resolved.year = 2000 AND
$intent.params.birthdate.resolved.month = 1 AND
$intent.params.birthdate.resolved.day > 1)
```

Here are examples for your reference:

A. Using the condition in the Conditional Response
[image: Conditional Response]

B. Using the condition as the Condition Route:
[image: Condition Route]

Please note that the birthdate parameter isn’t a string parameter. It is composed of year, month, and day sub-parameters so it is appropriate to utilize them for your use case. Also, note that dates are in ISO-8601 format. For more information, you can refer to the [System Entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/system-entities) documentation.

Here are the following results using the condition defined in the conditional response:

1. When the user enters the same year but not January 1st
   [image: 1]
2. When the user enters an invalid date
   [image: 2]
3. When the user enters a previous date from 2000-01-01
   [image: 3]
4. When the user enters a valid date and latest from 2000-01-01
   [image: 4]

Answer (score 0):

I guess `$intent.params.dob.resolved` returns a string, so you need to build a date object firstly, and then compare it with your date.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem a few weeks ago. Thing is, Dialogflow actually defaults to string parameters: this means that every value entered as a parameter will (by default) be a string, surrounded by "quotes".
To operate comparisons between dates you'd want to compare integers/numbers, and I think the best way to do so is to take advantage of **date system entities**.

For example, the system entity

```
@sys.date
```

allows you to match a date inserted by the user. Then the best part is, in your condition, you can even manage the date by **referencing sub-parts**. Here is an example:

```
if $intent.params.dob.year <= 2005 AND $intent.params.dob.month <= 04:
    I'm sorry, you're too young to use this service!
endif
```

Also, on a side note, "intent parameters" actually become "session parameters" as soon as Dialogflow makes a step from the state in which the parameter was set to another page.
This means that if you set the parameter *dob* when the user says "I was born on the thirteen of July, 2004" and then you go on to a new page, that parameter will only be accessible as $session.params.dob (and session parameters don't have a "resolved value", they are resolved by default).

So, to recap. Make sure you're using the *system date entity*. Make conditions for all the *parts of the date* you need to verify (year, month, day) and try to use your parameter as a *session parameter*.

I hope at least some of what I wrote can help you, happy bot-building!